# Flex to Html/Ajax converter

Tags: html, ajax, apache-flex

Is there a tool to convert Flex code to Html/Ajax code.
My Flex code primarily consists of datagrids/buttons/text labels..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; you'll have to do it manually.  Or write one yourself.

Why do you want to do this?